# Menu 2 efeitos: um para rolagem para abaixo e um para oposta

Tags: jquery, menu, rolamento

Olá,
Estou com dúvida sobre como fazer um menu (jquery).
Ele fica aparente ao topo do site, ao rodar 100 px do topo para baixo, ele se oculta (ok até aqui consegui fazer), e fica oculto até o final do site. 
Ao chegar ao fim, e a rolagem inversa acontecer, de baixo para o topo, o menu logo aparece, com um background (ativa outro css) e segue assim até o topo.
Que função chamo para identificar o scroll de baixo para cima?

Comment: Link útil: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Salve o scrollTop atual em uma variável e no próximo scroll verifique se foi maior ou menor:

```js
var scrollbkp = $(window).scrollTop(); // inicia a variável global com o scrollTop atual

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > scrollbkp) {
    // scroll para baixo
    console.log('para baixo');
  } else {
    // scroll para cima
    console.log('para cima');
  }
  scrollbkp = $(window).scrollTop(); // regrava o scrollTop para verificar na próxima vez
});
```

```css
.conteudo {
height: 2500px;
background-color:#ddd;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
max-height: 50px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conteudo">
conteudo...
</div>
```